# PHP MYSQL $row[$variable]

Tags: php, mysql, database, row, fetch

I am trying to work around with dynamic table creation and data fetching. I am trying to get the data using following code :

```
    $myQuery = "SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$tabname." WHERE sampleid='".$sid."'";
    $result = mysql_query($myQuery);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<br>".$row['$col_name'];
```

But, I am unable to get any data back. I checked printing the query and running it in php my admin and its working as I want. But I guess variable in array might not be working I guess.
Please help me regarding the same. Thanks.

The Whole loop looks something like this :

```
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tabname'";
$re = mysql_query($myQuery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($re)){
         if(!empty ($row)){
                    $col_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];

          $myQuery = "SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$tabname." WHERE sampleid='".$sid."'";
                    echo "<br>".$myQuery;
                    $reqq = mysql_query($myQuery);
                    $roww = mysql_fetch_array($reqq);
                    echo "<br>".$roww[$col_name];

                    }
                }
```

Comment: In between the first two lines there can you do an `echo $myQuery;` and put the response here?
Also maybe the results from `var_dump($row);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are fetching an array, not an [assoc array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). Use this:

```
echo "<br>".$row[0];
```

Edit: Having looked a little more, this may not be correct. You can set fetch_array to return assoc arrays.

You cannot parse variables through single quotes '

```
echo $row['col_name'];  // manually typed string.
```

or

```
echo $row[$col_name];
```

or

```
echo $row["$col_name"];
```

Comment: Thanks That worked quite well. The last option worked right. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

You tried that->

```
echo "<br>".$row[$col_name];
```

OR

```
    $myQuery = "SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$tabname." WHERE sampleid='".$sid."'";
    $result = mysql_query($myQuery);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<br>".$row[$col_name];
```

Cause like said @Fluffeh it's not a associative array

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping through the results array as such:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['col_name'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution. Give the parameter `$col_name` and `AS Col_Name`
Then the $row['Col_Name'] can always be set to the parameter no matter what the value.

```
$myQuery = "SELECT ".$col_name." AS Col_Name FROM ".$tabname." WHERE sampleid='".$sid."'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($myQuery); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    echo "<br>".$row['Col_Name'];
```