# How to use value of variable in $row[]; in php?

Tags: php, sql

I can't use variable inside of $row[];

```
$a = id
```

Then when I do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID='$id'";

$result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))
{
$aa = $row[$a];
  }

}
```

Then when I

```
echo $aa
```

I'm not getting the expected result. $aa should then return value like 193, since that is value in id column. It's the

```
 $aa = $row[$a];
```

part that appears to not be working.

Comment: Change `$a = id` to `$a = 'ID'`. hope it will works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MYSQL $row\[$variable\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752333/php-mysql-rowvariable)

Answer (score 0):

use `array_push()`. See documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
array_push($row, $a)
```

**applying this in your code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID='".$id."'";

$result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))
    {
        $aa = $row[];
        array_push($aa, $a)
    }
    print_r($aa);

}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with array_push, however, i'm not trying to add to the array, I'm mainly trying to get the value 'id' to appear in row, so that when I use my_sqli_fetch_assoc, it returns the value for id column

Comment: i see, i think this one one should be ` ID='".$id."'";`

Comment: appears to break it :/

Comment: Here's the thing. If I do this: $aa = $row[$a]; and replace it as: $aa = $row['id]; then when I echo $aa i get desired result, and it shows '193' (id of that record) but I don't always know column name since I'm allowing user to create fields from front end. That's why I'm trying to use something like $a - because that variable is simply a being created from doing an array and saving value like this: $a = $rows[0]; And when I echo $a i get  'id' but then I want to plug that variable into the new $row[]; if that makes sense